# Mini version of search filter for jqm listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using a list view with a [search filter bar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html) enabled.

It seems like data-mini attribute  ( `data-mini = true` ) is [not available](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html) out-of-box. Is there any way that I can use the mini version of search box within listview?

Answer (score 0):

you always can override your CSS and invent your "own" `data-mini=true` for listviews, [see docu](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify. The set of of theme classes (global) and semantic structural
>   classes (widget-specific) added to elements provide a rich set of
>   possible selectors against which to target style overrides. We
>   recommend adding an external stylesheet to the head, placed after the
>   structure and theme stylesheet references, that contain all your style
>   overrides. This allows you to easily update to newer versions of the
>   library because overrides are kept separate from the library code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about search filter bar then you should know tha data-mini = true can be applied to it.

Here is an example:

```
<input type="search" id="searchField" data-inline="true" placeholder="Search" data-mini = true>
```

And an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nXHNg/5/) on jsFiddle.